# i Want To Display Only One line Masseges Into page

Tags: jquery, html

I Have Code For One Search Box and Search button, when I search item(this all are hidden) and Press Search It Will Display If Item Found And If Not Found Then It will Display Massage many time I Want to display it only once  How Can I do ?

```js
$('.contact-name').hide();
$('#search').click(function() {
  $('.contact-name').hide();
  var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
  $('.contact-name').each(function() {
    if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
    } else {
      document.write("Not Available");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">11023</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">IronMan</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##"> Avaialable </a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Thor</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Hulk</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Mr.Bean</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">X-man</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Fury</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Captain</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Hery</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Robot</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Batman</a></h3>
</div>
<div class="contact-name">
  <h3><a href="##">Super man</a></h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set flag value for displying message in proper way.

Here is the solution you are searching for..Hope it will help you

```js
$('.contact-name').hide();
$('#search').click(function() {
    var matchFound = false;
    $('.contact-name').hide();
    var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
    $('.contact-name').each(function() {
       if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
          matchFound = true;
          $(this).show();
       }
    })
   if(!matchFound){
        document.write("Not Available");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="search-criteria" />
<input type="button" id="search" value="search" />
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">11023</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">IronMan</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##"> Avaialable </a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Thor</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Hulk</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Mr.Bean</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">X-man</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Fury</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Captain</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Hery</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Robot</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Batman</a></h3></div>
<div class="contact-name"><h3><a href="##">Super man</a></h3></div>
```

Comment: Thank You For Help This Is Work Thank A Lot Sir

Answer (score 0):

You can have a variable that indicates, whether the search item is found. After completing the search cycle, check the value of this variable and print the not-found message.

```
var match = false;

$('.contact-name').hide();
var txt = $('#search-criteria').val();
$('.contact-name').each(function() {
   if ($(this).text().toUpperCase().indexOf(txt.toUpperCase()) != -1) {
      $(this).show();
      match = true;
   }
});

if (!match) {
    document.write("Not Available");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One idea is first you can give 'id' to all your div tag and in your JS code just check the string input is same as id then remove the hidden tag from div.

```
if ($('#idtagname').val() == txt)
      $('#idtagname').show()
```

Comment: @dwjohnston , It was such a big mistake made from my part that you have to take time to correct it. i really appreciate you man. if you were not there then no one in this world would have ever understand it.

Answer (score 0):

Call a function that will show a div class that was hidden, and show it with the error.

Check if div is already visible, if it is, then you don't need to apply any logic.

Still since you are inside a each function, it will be triggered as many times as the elements of the class

First place something like this:

Then instead of using:

```
document.write("Not Available");
```

Do something like this:

```
if($('.error').is(":hidden")){
    $('.error').show();
    $('.error').text("There isn't any div to show");
}
```